# Money Gem - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, currency

I'm trying to use money gem in my machine but I'm getting following error.

I'm referring this link - https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/README.md

```
Money.new(1000, "USD").exchange_to("EUR")
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/dev/new_hotspotting-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/money-currencylayer-bank-0.5.3/lib/money/bank/currencylayer_bank.rb:93:in `update_rates'
    from /home/dev/new_hotspotting-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/money-currencylayer-bank-0.5.3/lib/money/bank/currencylayer_bank.rb:142:in `expire_rates!'
    from /home/dev/new_hotspotting-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/money-currencylayer-bank-0.5.3/lib/money/bank/currencylayer_bank.rb:108:in `get_rate'
    from /home/dev/new_hotspotting-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/money-6.7.0/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:109:in `exchange_with'
    from /home/dev/new_hotspotting-backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/money-6.7.0/lib/money/money.rb:434:in `exchange_to'
    from (irb):17
```

I'm not understand why I'm getting this error.
I'm using following version for money gems

```
money (6.9.0, 6.7.0)
money-currencylayer-bank (0.5.4)
```

[image]

Comment: I also trying to change version of money gems, but still getting same problems.

Comment: other functions of money gems are working but only exchange_to is not working

Comment: To do `exchange` you must [provide a rate source](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/README.md#currency-exchange).

Comment: @mudasobwa, still getting same error, I doing following
require 'money'

Money.add_rate("USD", "CAD", 1.24515)

Money.new(1000, "USD").exchange_to("CAD")

Comment: @TomLord that is wrong, there is no name conflict. I believe, `money-currencylayer-bank` requires _an authorization within the respective rate service_ and does not handle the auth failed gracefully.

Comment: @mudasobwa Hmm, I think you're right... It would be infinitely more helpful if OP could provide a [Minimal, COMPLETE, and VERIFIABLE Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: (i.e. Not just "within my rails console, where who-knows-what has been configured and loaded")

Comment: Temporary workaround could be calling `Money.new(1000, "USD").exchange_to("EUR") {|x| x}`. Try it out and tell me what does it do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

object requires one to manually specify the exchange rate

```
Money.add_rate("USD", "EUR", 0.5)
Money.us_dollar(100).exchange_to("EUR")
```

for more [official GEM rapo](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money)

output :

```
2.3.0 :009 >   
2.3.0 :010 >   require 'money'
 => true 
2.3.0 :011 > Money.add_rate("USD", "EUR", 0.5)
 => 0.5 
2.3.0 :012 > Money.us_dollar(100).exchange_to("EUR").currency
 => #<Money::Currency id: eur, priority: 2, symbol_first: true, thousands_separator: ., html_entity: &#x20AC;, decimal_mark: ,, name: Euro, symbol: €, subunit_to_unit: 100, exponent: 2, iso_code: EUR, iso_numeric: 978, subunit: Cent, smallest_denomination: 1> 
2.3.0 :013 > 
2.3.0 :014 >
```

Comment: can you send your code, you make some minor mistake on your code . please update your question with code

Comment: I uploaded image. please check it.

Comment: please reinstall money gem, because i recently check this i working fine on my linux.

Comment: my gem version is money-6.9.0

Comment: please see your pic require 'money' gives false on production env... in your porduction .env money gem in not proper include into your project

Comment: @vipin please stop suggesting wrong reinstalls. `require` is **intended to return `false` when the gem is already loaded**.

Comment: firstly check this runs on development env ---> only with rails c, then check on other or you can check on irb